# Creating a trigger in postgres claims that function does not exist, even though it is visible in \df

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prepare_audit() RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
DO
$$
DECLARE
_sql text;
BEGIN
FOR _sql IN
SELECT format('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS audit.%I_%I(timestamp timestamptz NOT NULL, entity jsonb NOT NULL)'
, schemaname
, tablename)
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_tables  -- only tables and partitioned tables, no toast tables
WHERE  schemaname = 'public'
LOOP
EXECUTE _sql;
END LOOP;
END
$$;
DO
$$
DECLARE
_sql text;
BEGIN
FOR _sql IN
SELECT format('DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS audittrigger on %I.%I; CREATE TRIGGER audittrigger AFTER INSERT ON %I.%I FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.audit_logger("audit.%I_%I")'
, schemaname
, tablename
, schemaname
, tablename
, schemaname
, tablename)
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_tables  -- only tables and partitioned tables, no toast tables
WHERE  schemaname = 'public'
LOOP
EXECUTE _sql;
END LOOP;
END
$$;
END
$func$;
```

This is a function which, when called, should find all tables in the public schema, and for each one:

- create a table on the audit schema called `public_<original_table_name>`
- create a trigger on the public table

The issue is that when it tries to create the trigger, it claims that `public.audit_logger()` does not exist. However, when I run `\df`, there is definitely a function called `audit_logger` on the `public` schema. What am I missing?

Comment: _shrug_, I'm new to SQL like this, so I wouldn't expect it to be pretty! Does the return value it matter if I just want to create the trigger?

Comment: You have to return a table row, typically `OLD` or `NEW` or NULL. See the documentation.

Comment: Return from the trigger itself?

Comment: Yes, it very much matters.  It might just throw away your insert. See the [create trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtrigger.html) documentation and the chapter on [Triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/trigger-definition.html)